# transfer learning with bad computer

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to use transfer learning to classify image. That my first try using transfer learning. I curently use VGG16 model. Since my data are very different from image  used for the original training model, theory told me I should train many layers, potentialy including hidden layers.

My computer has 8GO ram, using i5 2.40 Hz no gpu. My data set is small (3000 images), but data are stored as matrix in python memory, not saved in a folder. Almost all my RAM is takent by those images

Original VGG16 model has 130 million parameters. If I only take weight of hiden layer, and create 2 new (and small, size 512 and 256) fully connected layer at the end, I still have 15M parameter to train, for a total of 30m parameter.

I actually use image size of 224*224 like vgg16 input

My computer need 1H30 for 1 epoch. At 10 epoch I have a bad accuracy (50% vs 90% with conv net from scratch).

My question:

- computer crash after X epoch, I don't know why. Could it be RAM problem? Since when vgg started to train for 1 epoch, and other epoch are just weight adjustement, other epoch should not impact memory?
- Should I unfreeze input layer to use image of reduced dimension to reduce memory problem and training time? It'll not affect too much conv net performance?
- Is it normal to need 1h30 to compute 1 epoch with 15M trainable parameter? Since I still need to find optimal number of layer to unfreeze, shape of new fully connected layer, learning rate, otpimizer... it's look impossible to me to optimise a transfer learning model with my curent commputing ressources in a decent amount of time

Do you have any tips to for transfer learning?

thanks

Comment: maybe this helps a little bit: https://towardsdatascience.com/optimize-your-cpu-for-deep-learning-424a199d7a87. your computer is not really make for deep learning, this is some number. What about reduce your dataset to randomly 1000 images/ same distribution as original dataset? maybe this also works good

Comment: Your computer probably crashes due to overheating, so try to keep watch on the temperature of your machine (also, there are safeguards in computers that shuts down or throttles the computer or particular device like the CPU if the temperature crosses a particular value). If there is a memory full problem, it should probably throw an error (it does so when GPU memory is full, don't know about when GPU is not used)

Answer (score 1):

No specific tips for transfer learning, but if you are lacking on computing power, it might be helpful to consider transitioning to cloud resources. AWS, Google cloud, Azure or other services are available at really reasonable prices.

Most of them also provide some free resources, which can be enough for small ML projects or student tasks.
Notably:

- [Google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) provides a [free GPU for a limited time](https://python.gotrained.com/google-colab-gpu-deep-learning/#Connecting_to_Server_and_Setting_up_GPU_Runtime)
- AWS provides ~ [250 hours of training per month on sagemaker](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?tag=duckduckgo-d-20&all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=productcategories%23ai)
- Azure notebooks also [provides some free (but limited) computing power](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notebooks/azure-notebooks-overview)

Most of these services also provide free general compute power, on which you can also run ML tasks, but that might require some additional manual tweaking.